# при компиляции python проекта в один файл не удается передать доп файлы и папки

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Если я с помощью pyinstaller компилилю проект в виде папки, передавая доп. нужные для меня файлы, все работает замечательно.

> py -3.9 -m PyInstaller --add-data 'data.json;.' --add-data 'platforms;platforms' main.py

Но если я хочу сделать в виде одного файла, ничего не работает, так-как моя прога не видит папку platforms и json.

> py -3.9 -m PyInstaller -F --add-data 'data.json;.' --add-data 'platforms;platforms' main.py

Answer (score 0):

Ваши файлы, добавленные ключом(ами) `--add-data`, упаковуются в тот же `exe` потому что вы указали, что хотите получить один файл.
Вы можете это увидеть, если пройдете по пути, который хранится в переменной `__file__`. В этой папке будут все ваши файлы, добавленные ключом(ами) `--add-data`.
Соответственно, чтобы обращаться к этим файлам нужно немного изменить код.

---

**Вариант 1**:
Изменить текущий рабочий каталог. Это позволит вам открывать файлы как вы это делали раньше, например:

```
import os
os.chdir('/'.join(__file__.split('\\')[:-1]))

with open('some.txt', 'r') as file: 
    text = file.read()
```

---

**Вариант 2**:
Можно перед каждым обращением к файлу прописывать этот путь. Это выглядит так:

```
__FILE__PATH__ = '/'.join(__file__.split('\\')[:-1]) + '/'

with open(__FILE__PATH__+'some.txt', 'r') as file: 
    text = file.read()
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это не помогло. В папке platforms находятся dll, с которыми работает pyqt5, а я с ними никак не взаимодействую и не могу также как и с data.json просто добавить твой код. Вот ошибка, которая выходит в консоли при попытке запуска программы: qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Comment: @Yant для этого используйте `pyqtdeploy`

Comment: @Yant или можно использовать `--add-binary`, а не `--add-data`

Comment: @Yant к тому же упаковка `dll` обычно не делается. их просто "оставляют рядом" с `exe`. Потому что, если они упакованы в `exe` - их нужно заново качать при обновлении программы. А разделение `dll` и `exe` позволяет загрузить лишь обновленный `exe` файл.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло то, что я добавил в код:

```
import PyQt5
import os

pyqt = os.path.dirname(PyQt5.__file__)
os.environ['QT_PLUGIN_PATH'] = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(pyqt, "Qt/plugins"))
```

И во-вторых, вместо этого:

> --add-data 'platforms;platforms'

вписал это:

> --add-data 'PyQt5;PyQt5'

Предварительно добавив эту папку в проект и подчистив ее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полностью команда в моем случае выглядит так:

> py -3.9 -m PyInstaller --add-data 'data.json;.' --add-data 'PyQt5;PyQt5' --hidden-import "os" -F main.py

---

PS Но осталась только проблема с JSON, программа его видит, но если изменить в нем что-то и перезапустить программу, все что изменил, исчезнет.